# I need to add ease in effect to my code

Tags: jquery

I have to add easein effect for my animate function. Here below my codes

```
$('.img_left').animate({ 'margin-left' : '180px', 'opacity' : '1'}, 3000);
```

Pls help me

Comment: .animate( properties [, duration] [, easing] [, complete] )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vanilla jQuery supports only `linear` and `swing` easing options. More options are found in the jQuery UI suite.

To use them you do:

```
$('.img_left').animate({ 'margin-left' : '180px', 'opacity' : '1'}, 3000, 'linear');
```